# JQuery Cycle, just stop resizing

Tags: jquery, plugins, resize, cycle

I'm making a horizontal scrolling site. All images have a height of 100% and the width is on auto. I want to use Cycle on these images, which works, but it puts my images on their original huge size instead of scaling them to the window height. I already tried using slideResize: false, which didn't do anything. Fit: true didn't do anything either, and containerResize: false makes my image disappear! Also, putting !important on the css height: 100% did not seem to help. How can I just keep my image at their 100% height??

These are the scripts i'm using in head:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://malsup.github.io/jquery.cycle.all.js"></script>
```

HTML:

```
<body>

<div id="container">

<div id="vinyl">
    <img src="images/vinyl1.jpg">
    <img src="images/vinyl2.jpg">
    <img src="images/vinyl3.jpg">
</div>
</div>

</body>
```

And here's the javascript:

```
$('#vinyl').cycle({
    next: '#vinyl',
    timeout: 0,
    containerResize: 0
});
```

CSS:

```
html{
    overflow-y: hidden;
}

body{
    margin: 0 0 0 0;
    padding: 0 0 0 0;
    overflow-x: scroll;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    font-family: Helvetica;
    font-size: 16pt;
    background-color: white;
    height: 100%;
}

img {
    height: 100%;
    width: auto;
    z-index: 997;
}

#container{
    width: 100000px;
    height: 100%;
}

#iwpb, #vooruit, #vinyl{
    height: 100%;
    width: auto;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    margin: 0 15px 0 0;
    padding: 0 0 0 0;
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: can you make a JSFiddle or a CodePen ?

Comment: I'm trying to but it doesn't seem to work, never made a jsFiddle before :/

Comment: I think I misunderstood your question, but here's a fiddle of your code: http://jsfiddle.net/j45Vz/3/

Comment: thank you for that! So the problem is the images should just be as heigh as the browser window, but Cycle makes them much bigger (original file size). Any ideas?

Comment: here's a zip of the website, sorry for the file size! https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7nPZtcjMPQGRTdjcG5USXVrcFk/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: don't ever think anyone will download your files. Might consider using cycle2 which has better responsive capabilites

Comment: Sorry, thought it might help. I'm giving cycle2 a try tomorrow ;)

Comment: cycle2 is a success, problem solved; thanks a lot!

Comment: maybe you can post your code, as an answer, then select it as solution.